# Playwright Media Keys using Keyboard

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to press the Media keys on the keyboard using Playwright / Typescript. For example, when playing audio using a browser, users are able to press 'Play/Pause, Forward, Backward' using the media keys on their keyboard. According to the documentation (https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-keyboard)(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values), I should be able to use something like this:

```
await page.keyboard.press('MediaStop');
```

However I get the error:

```
Error: keyboard.press: Unknown key: "MediaStop"
```

I've also tried:

```
await page.keyboard.press('MediaPlayPause');
```

Am I missing something here?

Thank you

Comment: "According to the documentation" — a link to the specific part of the documentation you are referring to would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I added it. I've updated the question accordingly. Thank you